# Deserialize XML to Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, xmlserializer

I try to deserialize XML to dictionary.

Here is my XML:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfTableRow1 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <TableRow1>
    <Code>A</Code>
    <Explanation>Spital</Explanation>
  </TableRow1>
  <TableRow1>
    <Code>B</Code>
    <Explanation>Heim</Explanation>
  </TableRow1>
  <TableRow1>
    <Code>C</Code>
    <Explanation>Spitex</Explanation>
  </TableRow1>
</ArrayOfTableRow1>
```

Now I load it in a XDocument. This is working correct. After I try it to deserialize to Dictionary. This gives me an `ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: TableRow1`

```
var xdc = XDocument.Load(...);
var dic = xdc.Descendants("ArrayOfTableRow1").Descendants()
              .ToDictionary(element => element.Name, element => element.Value);
```

Can someone help me, how I can serialize my XML to a Dictionary<string, string> with

```
{{"A", "Spital"}, {"B", "Heim"}, ...}
```

Comment: IMHO, create a class that conforms to your xml structure and deserialize to it. Then you can do what ever you want with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dic = xdc.Descendants("ArrayOfTableRow1")
             .Elements()
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Element("Code").Value, 
                           x => x.Element("Explanation").Value);
```

---

You don't want `Descendants` of `ArrayOfTableRow1`, you want only the immediate children, so use `Elements`.  Then, as you loop over each `TableRow1`, grab the `Code` and `Explanation` values.

Note that this doesn't include any error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("TableRow1")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("Code"), y => (string)y.Element("Explanation"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```